# How to close response body without reading the response body in okhttp3

Tags: okhttp

Environment

- MacOS
- JDK 11
- okhttp-4.9.0

The environment I'm working on is quite sensitive with the network bandwidth.
Sometimes, I don't need to read all the response body. A part of the response body could be enough to decide a result.

I want to close the response(=response body) **without reading the body**.

What do I want to do is like below

```java
try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
    assertThat(response.code(), is(200))
    // do nothing with the response body
}
```

But, when the connection is established with HTTP1, the `ResponseBody::close` invokes `Http1ExchangeCodec.FixedLengthSource::close` in the end.

**Http1ExchangeCodec.FixedLengthSource::close**

```kotlin
override fun close() {
    if (closed) return

    if (bytesRemaining != 0L &&
        !discard(ExchangeCodec.DISCARD_STREAM_TIMEOUT_MILLIS, MILLISECONDS)) {
    connection.noNewExchanges() // Unread bytes remain on the stream.
    responseBodyComplete()
    }

    closed = true
}
```

Then, the `discard` method reads all the response body source as below.

**Util.kt**

```kotlin
fun Source.discard(timeout: Int, timeUnit: TimeUnit): Boolean = try {
    this.skipAll(timeout, timeUnit)
} catch (_: IOException) {
    false
}

@Throws(IOException::class)
fun Source.skipAll(duration: Int, timeUnit: TimeUnit): Boolean {
    val nowNs = System.nanoTime()
    val originalDurationNs = if (timeout().hasDeadline()) {
        timeout().deadlineNanoTime() - nowNs
    } else {
        Long.MAX_VALUE
    }
    timeout().deadlineNanoTime(nowNs + minOf(originalDurationNs, timeUnit.toNanos(duration.toLong())))
    return try {
        val skipBuffer = Buffer()
        while (read(skipBuffer, 8192) != -1L) {
            skipBuffer.clear()
        }
        true // Success! The source has been exhausted.
    } catch (_: InterruptedIOException) {
        false // We ran out of time before exhausting the source.
    } finally {
        if (originalDurationNs == Long.MAX_VALUE) {
            timeout().clearDeadline()
        } else {
            timeout().deadlineNanoTime(nowNs + originalDurationNs)
        }
    }
}
```

It reads all the body and clears buffer. In my case, it's a waste of the CPU time and the network bandwidth.

Is there any way to just close it literally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Workaround

Even though I couldn't reuse the connection, I wanted to close connection without reading all the buffer to save network bandwidth and CPU.

To skip the reading all, I tried to change `Http1ExchangeCodec.FixedLengthSource`'s `bytesRemaining` field to 0. `bytesRemaining` is set by "Content-Length" response header value.
But, there's no way to change `bytesRemaining` even if changing the response header with custom interceptor.
Because, "Content-Length" is check whne the `CallServerInterceptor`(the last interceptor of interceptor chains) proceed the request so, `bytesRemaining` is set by the original response header.

Finally, I found that I can use the timeout deadline of `Source`. `Source.skipAll()` can be interrupted belong to timeout deadline. Set the timeout deadline to `0` to ensure timeout always occurs. This makes the connection close literally without reading remaining bytes.

```java
try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
    assertThat(response.code(), is(200))
    
    response.body()
        .source()
        .timeout()
        .deadlineNanoTime(0);
    // close without reading remaining bytes
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there's no way to immediately close the response body. If you never issue another HTTP request on that connection it is a waste of bandwidth and CPU. But it is necessary for the connection to be pooled.

Consider using a HEAD method or adding a [range header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Range) if you're not interested in the response body. That way you're also saving the server’s CPU and bandwidth.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I tried to build okhttp without `discard`. Then, I could find that the unit tests related to connection reuse was broken.
Even the connection can not be reused, I want to just close the connection. But, I couldn't find the way to handle it.